# how to create a new site navigation in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm just wondering if someone can show me the way of creating a new site navigation in magento,
I'm really lost,

I need to make a site navigation like Home, About us ,Brands and so on, it is in the header section, I know I should use block in page.xml but I just can't figure out how everything goes together.

any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

you can get this done by going through to the html folder found at... /app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/page/html/   ... and edit the header.phtml file.

another way that i like to add links to the header is creating a static block in the admin panel then referencing it in the header.phtml file using the following line:

getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('id_of_the_block_you_created')->toHtml(); ?>

this way if the links need changing it can be done through the admin panel.